# Reading in lines of numeric strings into separate lists in python

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file which has multiple lines of numeric string values of following format:

csv sample of 2 lines:

> [['ASA00211063', '2005'], [-0.434358, -0.793407, -1.070576, nan, nan,...(365 values)], [0.354615, -0.108102,nan,...(**365** values)]]
>
> [['AFR02516075', '1998'], [-0.434358, -0.7934039, -1.0705767, nan, nan,...(365 values)], [0.3546153, -0.1081022, nan,...(**365** values)]]

How can I split as well as join the csv file into lists, such that out put is:

```
list[0] = ['ASA00211063', '2005'], ['AFR02516075', '1998']...
list[1] = [-0.434358, -0.793407, -1.070576, nan, nan,..., 0.354615, -0.108102,nan,...(**730** values)]
list[2] = [-0.434358, -0.7934039, -1.0705767, nan, nan,..., 0.3546153, -0.1081022, nan,...(**730** values)]
```

Comment: does the csv contain the `[[` and  `]]` symbols?

Comment: Yes, it does have the [[ and ]] symbols and gets treated as strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I satisfied your requirements with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

data = [[]]

for line in open('in'):
    line = line.strip()
    line = re.match(r'\[?(.*)\]', line).group(1)

    res = re.split(r', (?=\[)', line)

    data[0].append(res[0])
    string = res[1] + res[2]
    data.append([string])

for i, v in enumerate(data):
    print("{}\n".format(data[i]))
```

Input:

```
[['ASA00211063', '2005'], [-0.434358, -0.793407, -1.070576, nan, nan,...(365 values)], [0.354615, -0.108102,nan,...(365 values)]]
[['AFR02516075', '1998'], [-0.434358, -0.7934039, -1.0705767, nan, nan,...(365 values)], [0.3546153, -0.1081022, nan,...(365 values)]]
[['XXX02516075', '1998'], [-1.434358, -1.7934039, -1.1705767, nan, nan,...(365 values)], [0.7546153, -0.7081022, nan,...(365 values)]]
```

Output:

```
data[0]:
["['ASA00211063', '2005']", "['AFR02516075', '1998']", "['XXX02516075', '1998']"]

data[1]:
['[-0.434358, -0.793407, -1.070576, nan, nan,...(365 values)][0.354615, -0.108102,nan,...(365 values)]']

data[2]:
['[-0.434358, -0.7934039, -1.0705767, nan, nan,...(365 values)][0.3546153, -0.1081022, nan,...(365 values)]']

data[3]:
['[-1.434358, -1.7934039, -1.1705767, nan, nan,...(365 values)][0.7546153, -0.7081022, nan,...(365 values)]']
```

Comment: Thanks @Stevieb. I will try this code snippet as well to learn how to use regex better as I was struggling with these. Much thanks

Answer (score 1):

To read a pythonic structure from a text file always use `ast.literal_eval()` it will only read in python structures and prevents anyone from embedding anything nasty in an input file.

This code will go through each line in your input file and append it to a list from which you can decide what to do.

```
import ast

l = []
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    edited_line = line.replace('nan','"nan"')
    l.append(ast.literal_eval(edited_line))
```

This will also replace all `nan` with `numpy.nan` objects:

```
import ast
from numpy import nan

l = []
for line in open('inputfile.txt'):
    edited_line = line.replace('nan','"nan"')
    edited_line = ast.literal_eval(edited_line)
    edited_line =  [[nan if v == 'nan' else v for v in vals] for vals in edited_line]
    l.append(edited_line)

# combine elements [1] and [2] in the sublist to a list of len = 730
# element l[0] is list of ['code', 'yyyy']
# element l[1 ... n] is list of data by row of length 730
l = [[subl[0] for subl in l]] + [subl[1]+subl[2] for subl in l]
```

gives output:

```
for row in l: print row
>>> [['ASA00211063', '2005'], ['AFR02516075', '1998']]
    [-0.434358, -0.793407, -1.070576, nan, nan, 0.354615, -0.108102, nan]
    [-0.434358, -0.7934039, -1.0705767, nan, nan, 0.3546153, -0.1081022, nan]
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidence. I am getting following TypeError. any further guidence.

TypeError: literal_eval() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, I get a "ValueError: malformed string" and I was suspecting it could be nan in my strings

Comment: @ASG hope that's solved your problem... I've also added an adjustment to convert all `nan` to `numpy` objects

Comment: Thanks so much @alexmcf, I will try that code snippet now

Comment: Quick question. I see that len(l[0][1]) is 365 and len(l[0][2]) is 365. If I were to combine these two one list. what is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: @ASG I've edited it to give the output you were after. `l[0]` contains a list of `['code', 'yyyy']` and `l[0, ... ,n]` contains the rest of your data. Hopefully this is useful as it will allow you to use the values directly in python afterwards. Let me know if that helps